# Histogram of time between two date fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, histogram, aggregation, date-histogram

I have records in ElasticSearch database where each record has CreatedAt and UpdatedAt fields. I want to generate a histogram of time durations between UpdatedAt and CreatedAt field values. How can I do this?

```
{
    “Id”: 6002,
    “customerName”: MX, 
    “CreatedAt”: "2022-12-01T10:15:32.133Z",
    “fieldId”: "2022-12-10T17:25:45.133Z",
    “fieldType”: typeC,
    “fieldId”: 1003
   
}
```